# Where does this List price come from in opportunity Products

Tags: administration, opportunity-lineitem

There is a field called list price in opportunity Product. 
From where does this field get populated from? 
[image]

EDIT :
From the documentation

> Corresponds to the UnitPrice on the PricebookEntry that is associated
>   with this line item, which can be in the standard pricebook or a
>   custom pricebook. A client application can use this information to
>   show whether the unit price (or sales price) of the line item differs
>   from the pricebook entry list price.

Does this mean that List price holds the price from pricebook entry and salesprice hold the value entered while creating the opp line item?
Thanks

Comment: :Can u clarify this doubt If we want to default the Price value then which price is to be taken (sales price or unit price)

Comment: I am unclear on what you mean by default the price. List price is the price that is defined in the pricebook and (unitprice or salesprice) is the price that you are defining for this particular opportunity. This is the actual selling price, while creating a oli the unit price is defaulted with the list price value, but this value can be changed/overridden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct, the ListPrice is the 'Unit Price' in the PriceBook Entry that the Opportunity Line Item has been created from. When creating an OLI, the Sales Price (UnitPrice) and List Price (ListPrice) defaults to the UnitPrice in the PriceBookEntry, but can be overridden to a different value.

The Total Price takes the Sales Price into account and is calculated as Sales Price X Quantity (less any Discount)

[image]

Comment: Hey can you clear my little doubt here: <br/>
As explained about List Price   <br/> **the ListPrice is the 'List Price' in the PriceBook Entry that the Opportunity Line Item has been created from and When creating an OLI, the Sales Price defaults to the ListPrice in the PriceBookEntry,**   <br/> Then how is *Unit Price* be defined ?